# How do I solve these Vector questions?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

The equations of two planes are,

**(6i − 3j + 2k) = 42** and
**(17i + 2j + k) = −7**

The straight line **l** is the intersection of the two planes.

a) How do I find an equation for **l**, in the form **r = a + λb**, where **a** and **b** are *constant vectors* and **λ** is a *scalar parameter*?

Now, A third **Φ** contains **l** and the point with position vector **30i + 7j + 30k**

b) How do I find an equation for **Φ**, in the form **r = u + αv + βw**, where **u**, **v** and **w** are *constant vectors* and **α** and **β** are *scalar parameters*?

Comment: Your equations of the plane are not correct. The objects on the left are vectors and on the right you have scalars.

Comment: First, find the line of intersection by solving the two equations. Then, using that equation, find two points on the line by picking special values and solving for the remaining variables. I typically choose $0$ as much as I can for a special value. Call the position vectors of the two points $P_0$ and $P_1$. The vector $P_1-P_0$ will be in the direction of the line (why?) and since $P_0$ is on the line you can parameterize the line as $P_0 + t(P_1-P_0) = (1-t)P_0 + tP_1$ (again, why?). This all works in two dimensions too so it helps to sketch the vectors to understand what's happening.

Comment: @JohnDouma I believe $i,j$ and $k$ are meant to be variables, not the canonical basis vectors. Then they would be affine planes.

Comment: @CyclotomicField You may be correct. That makes sense but she later uses those variables as unit vectors.

Comment: This is not a "please do my homework for me" site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean planes $6x-3y+2z=42$ and $17x+2y+z=(-7)$

The straight line $\ell$ would stand for the solutions common to these planes

To find the line, we need a point (any point) which lies on the line and it's direction ratios.

DIRECTION RATIOS:

The normal to the planes are along $\lt 6,-3,2 \gt$ and $\lt 17,2,1\gt$ respectively

now the direction of the line must be perpendicular to both of these ratios (because the line lies on both the planes, and these are normals to the plane)

Thus their vector product (or cross product) would give the vector along the line (and thus it's direction ratios)

$$(6\hat{i} -3\hat{j} +2\hat{k})\times (17\hat{i} +2\hat{j} +\hat{k})
= -7\hat{i} +28\hat{j} +73\hat{k}$$

thus the direction ratios of our line are $\lt-7,28,73\gt$

ANY POINT ON THE LINE:

since we need any point, i can apply a constraint to both planes to make it easier. We are sure that the line must cross the $yz$ plane, so i can put $x=0$

$$6x-3y+2z=42 \\  17x+2y+z=(-7)$$
$$\implies -3y+2z=42 \\  2y+z=(-7)$$
$$ \implies y=-8, z=9$$

thus the point $(0,-8,9)$ must lie on our line.

LINE:

thus the required equation of our line $\ell$ is $r= -8\hat{j} +9\hat{k} +\lambda (-7\hat{i} +28\hat{j} +73\hat{k})$

FOR THE $\Phi$ PART:

$\Phi$ is a plane containing line $\ell$ and the point $30\hat{i}+ 7\hat{j}+ 30\hat{k}$ and has to be expressed as $r = \vec{u} + α\vec{v} + β\vec{w}$

again, $\vec{u}$ just needs to be a point on the plane, and since the line contains $30\hat{i}+ 7\hat{j}+ 30\hat{k}$ , we can let $\vec{u}$ be just that.

vectors $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ just control the span of our plane, so the direction ratios of our line $\ell$ and a vector from $30\hat{i}+ 7\hat{j}+ 30\hat{k}$ to any point on the line would suffice.

thus $\vec{v}$ can be $-7\hat{i} +28\hat{j} +73\hat{k}$

and $\vec{w}$ can be $(30-0)\hat{i}+ (7+8)\hat{j}+ (30-9)\hat{k}$

i.e. $30\hat{i} +15\hat{j} +21\hat{k}$

thus $\Phi$ becomes $r=30\hat{i}+ 7\hat{j}+ 30\hat{k}+ \alpha (-7\hat{i} +28\hat{j} +73\hat{k}) +\beta (30\hat{i} +15\hat{j} +21\hat{k})$

NOTE: these aren't
unique solutions, and there can be infinitely many solutions to this problem. so just concentrate on the methods used and not the answer derived.